# Rounding value with 2 decimal points in c#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

```
double number1 = 4.1870418700000007d;
```

I tried with following :

**Input :** `Math.Ceiling(number1)`
**Output :** 5

**Input :** `Math.Round(number1)`
**Output :** 4

I want output : `4.19`

Comment: What about `Math.Round(number1, 2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, it's `Math.Round(number1, 2)`. It takes an overload that accepts the number of decimal places.